# Firefox extension: allow new tab opening

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I've written a  Chrome extension, which works like expected. It opens after button click a new tab with function `void(window.open('https://example.com#url='+window.location.href,'_blank'));`

**My problem now**: on trying to use this extension as Firefox extension, the Firefox alerts me `Firefox prevented this site from opening popup window allow extension` and offers to setup popup settings.

**The question**: How could i adjust an extension to allow Firefox always open in new tab urls from type `https://example.com#url=http://any-other-url.com`

Comment: Use the extension API in your background script e.g. chrome.windows.create or chrome.tabs.create. If you need it in the content script, simply send a message to the background script which will then open the window/tab.

Comment: @wOxxOm My background script does it on this way `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "code.js"})
});` Could you please specify, what kind of change should be done?

Comment: In code.js use chrome.runtime.sendMessage, in background script use chrome.runtime.onMessage to register a listener function that will open a tab/window with the url passed from code.js in the message, see the [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) documentation for examples.